# What will be the new origin after three rotations around different origins?

Tags: geometry, transformation, rotations

Question: Write down the origin of the composition of three rotations:

1. Rotation by $45^\circ$ around $O_{1}$
2. Rotation by $-60^\circ$ around $O_{2}$
3. Rotation by $30^\circ$ around $O_{3}$

And write down the image of a triangle $ABC$ after each of these transformations.

I don't even know how to start.

Comment: Read page 12 of this paper: https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~kf262/MMM/L3/L3_2.pdf

Comment: Presumably all of this is going on in the Euclidean plane.